# Why 'datas' array is always empty?

Tags: javascript, massive

My code

```
 $.getJSON('/load4',
    function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var counter = data[i];
            datas.push([counter.Id, counter.login.substr(0, 25),'3', counter.hash , 'MA']); 
        }
    });
console.log("Datas " + datas);
```

I'm trying to fill my array like [[a,b],[a,c]], but can't.

```
datas[i] = [counter.Id, counter.login.substr(0, 25),'3', counter.hash , 'MA'];
```

Also doesn't work.

Comment: What's a "massive"?

Comment: add `console.log("Datas " + datas);` inside your `function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are loading your JSON **asynchronously**. Which means that the `log` runs **before** the callback function passed as parameter to `getJSON`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `console.log` inside your `function` instead of outside.

```
$.getJSON('/load4',
  function(data) {
    var datas = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var counter = data[i];
      datas.push([counter.Id, counter.login.substr(0, 25), '3', counter.hash, 'MA']);
    }
    console.log("Datas " + datas);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a variable datas first.

```
 var datas =[];   
 $.getJSON('/load4',
        function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var counter = data[i];
                datas.push([counter.Id, counter.login.substr(0, 25),'3', counter.hash , 'MA']); 
            }
        });
console.log("Datas " + datas);
```

Comment: if it doesn't work share your program in a snippet. Or else share the json data format. thanks.

Comment: That array will still be empty in the `console.log`.  See the duplicate I linked to.

Comment: `datas` will still be empty because the call to fill it is asynchronous.